# Unable to remove lowest value from linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list

I created a linked-list in C. I'm trying to create a function that looks at the lowest value in the linked list (which is the head) and the removes the "right-most" instance of that value in the list.

Suppose the linked-list looks like this:

```
2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6
```

The head in this list is 2. But it's not the head I want to remove. I want to remove the 2 that comes before the 4 (it is the right-most instance of the head).

Here's the function I created to implement this:

```
double removeLowestValue() {
  struct node *temp;
  struct node *ptr = head;
  double val = ptr->value;
  if(head == tail)
  {
      free(head);
      head = NULL;
      tail = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
      while(ptr->value == ptr->next->value)
      {
          temp = ptr;
          ptr = ptr->next;
          val = ptr->value
      }
      temp->next = NULL;
      temp->next = ptr->next;
      free(ptr);

      return val;
  }
}
```

Then I tried to test if the function works:

```
int main() {
  insertNode(18.0);
  insertNode(13.0);
  insertNode(11.0);
  insertNode(11.0);
  insertNode(22.0);

  printf("%d", removeLowestValue());

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the program doesn't print out "11" as expected. Matter of fact, it doesn't print anything at all. What's going on here?

EDIT:

Here's how I implemented the insertNode function:

```
void insertNode(double value) {
  struct node *new_node = create_new_node(value);
  struct node *temp = head;
  struct node *prev;

  if (head == NULL) {
    head = new_node;
    tail = new_node;
  } else {
    while (value > temp->value && temp->next != NULL) {
      prev = temp;
      temp = temp->next;
    }

    if(value < temp->value || value == temp->value)
    {
        /*If the value of the new node equals to the value of temp
         OR if the value of the new node is less than the value of temp,
         then insert the new node right before temp*/

        new_node->next = temp;
        prev->next = new_node;
    }
    else if(value > temp->value)
    {
        temp->next = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting a [mcve] would help a lot for us. Not sure what you meant here, the first statement is useless as you reassign it in the second statement: `temp->next = NULL;
      temp->next = ptr->next;`. And when `if(head == tail)` is true, no value is returned.

Comment: This seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: In addition to previous comments, your program will likely have a segfault on list `1->1->1`

Comment: where did the `head` come from in the `removeLastValue` function? i don't see if it's globally defined or passed to the function itself....

Comment: where is the comparison to find lowest value?

Comment: `printf("%d", removeLowestValue());` is wrong since removeLowestValue returns double. You should use "%lf"

Comment: @Auxilus The head is globally defined and is assigned in the insertNode() function (if the list is already empty).

Comment: removeLowestValue() called on an empty list will generate error since you'll try to free NULL pointer

Comment: @qxg Based on how I implemented the insertNode function (which works fine btw), the lowest value is always the head. However, more nodes that hold the same value as the head can be inserted as shown in the description above.

Comment: @ShlomiAgiv Right, I'll get that fixed. But besides that, am I doing anything wrong in removeLowestValue() function?

Comment: Perhaps this will be clearer if I added my insertNode() function in the description above.

Comment: you're missing a ; on line 4

Comment: @ShlomiAgiv Fixed it. But I only made that mistake in the form, not in the IDE.

Comment: It should be noted, if the first ...or last entry is the same, then the contents of the linked list will be the same, regardless of if the first or last  entry is removed.  Since the list is 'ordered', Strongly suggest just say: `if( !head ), return 0.0; else {temp = head; head = head->next; val = temp->val; free( temp );  return val;  }`

Comment: @user3629249 I think you're misunderstanding my goal here. I want the program to remove the last node that contains the same value as the head. So even if all the value of the list were equal, then the function should return the last value, not the head. Another example is if the list looked like this: 2,2,2,2,2,6. In this case, the function should remove the last 2 in the last, that is the 2 right before the 6.

Comment: in the 'add node' function, when there is already 1 node in the linked list and the second node to be added contains a value lower than the existing node, then the variable: `prev` is not set, However, it is being used as if it contained a valid pointer.  The result is undefined behavior.  This needs to be corrected

Comment: Per your last comment, (all values being the same, then it does not matter which node  value is removed,  The value returned will always be the same

Comment: I understand. But in my case, the main function isn't printing anything at all. What I'm actually trying to do is to make sure that values are removed from the list in FIFO order. So if many nodes of the same value are inserted into the list, then the removeLowestValue function should remove the last instance of the lowest value (even if it's equal to the head), because that lowest value was inserted first. You can check my implementation of the insertNode function to see how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function corrected, of course that supposes the list is sorted :

```
double removeLowestValue() {
  if (head == NULL)
    return 0; /* ???? */
  else {
    node * ptr = head;
    node * previous = 0; /* the cell before the cell to remove */

    while ((ptr->next != NULL) && (ptr->value == ptr->next->value)) {
      previous = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    /* ptr is now the cell to remove */

    double val = ptr->value;

    if (ptr == head) {
      /* remove the first cell */
      ptr = head->next;
      free(head);
      head = ptr;
      if (head == NULL)
        /* the list is empty */
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else if (ptr->next == NULL) {
      /* all the values are the same in the list
         ptr is the last cell */
      free(ptr);
      /* previous is now the last cell */
      previous->next = NULL;
      tail = previous;
    }
    else {
      /* ptr is not the first nor the last cell */
      previous->next = ptr->next;
      free(ptr);
    }

    return val;
  }
}
```

---

Concerning *insertNode* :

- it is better to move the declaration of the variables *temp* and *prev* where they are useful, they are useless if *head* null so at the top of the definition
- `(value < temp->value || value == temp->value)` can be just `(value <= temp->value)` and the `else if (...)` after can be just an `else`
- when `(value <= temp->value)` *prev* can be still unset but used for `prev->next = new_node`, that appends when you insert 13 after 18 in your *main*. When `(temp == head)` you have to update *head* setting it with `new_node`

So the corrected version can be :

```
void insertNode(double value) {
  struct node *new_node = create_new_node(value);

  if (head == NULL) {
    head = new_node;
    tail = new_node;
  } else {
    struct node *temp = head;
    struct node *prev = 0; /* = 0 to be sure to have a crash if something wrong */

    while ((value > temp->value) && (temp->next != NULL)) {
      prev = temp;
      temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (value <= temp->value)
    {
        /* insert the new node right before temp*/
        new_node->next = temp;
        if (temp == head)
          head = new_node;
        else
          /* prev was set */
          prev->next = new_node;
    } else {
        /* insert the new node at end */
        temp->next = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Using the additional definitions

```
typedef struct node {
  double value;
  struct node * next;
} node;

node * create_new_node(double value)
{
  node * r = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

  r->value = value;
  r->next = 0;

  return r;
}

int main() {
  insertNode(18.0);
  insertNode(13.0);
  insertNode(11.0);
  insertNode(11.0);
  insertNode(22.0);

  printf("%g\n", removeLowestValue());
  printf("%g\n", removeLowestValue());
  printf("%g\n", removeLowestValue());
  printf("%g\n", removeLowestValue());
  printf("%g\n", removeLowestValue());
  printf("%g\n", removeLowestValue());

  return 0;
}
```

the execution writes (the last 0 indicate the list is empty)

```
11
11
13
18
22
0
```

Comment: It looks like you've made some changes that I don't want. For instance, you wrote `if (ptr->next == 0) {
    ptr = head;
  }`. If it did turn out that all the values are the same, then I don't want ptr to be set back to the head. It needs to stay as the last value of the list. Like I said the description, I want to remove the **rightmost** instance of the lowest value. So if the list looked list this: 2,2,2,2,2,2,2 then I want the last 2 to be removed. Not the first one.

Comment: Another mistake in your code is that you're checking if a node is null by comparing it to 0. I think the right way to do it is by comparing it to NULL. Also, I just tested your solution and it didn't work. The program still didn't print anything.

Comment: in my tests all was ok up to the empty list. WHat tests you did ? BTW I did not used you insert, I did the list by hand. NULL and 0 are the same, change to NULL if you prefer but in fact that change nothing at all

Comment: I tested it by running the main() function as shown in the description above. The program is supposed to print the lowest value (11), but it didn't print anything.

Comment: @BobK The problem is in your insert function, it does't work, after the 5 inserts in your main the list only contains 18 and 22

Comment: You're right. I just tested it and looks like there's something wrong with the way I'm writing lines 15-23 of the insertNode function. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @BobK I just see in case there was only one cell I didn't return its value, corrected

Comment: @BobK is it ok for you or not ?

Comment: Yeah your solution worked. I upvoted your answer. But I still can't give it best answer because you didn't remove the lines `if (ptr->next == 0) { ptr = head; }`. I don't want ptr to be set to head if all the values are the same.

Comment: @BobK now the removed cell is the last cell of the lower value